# Обноление драйвера для Radeon HD 7600M

Tags: драйвер, видеокарта, radeon

[image: Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как обновить драйвера на интегрированной видеокарте данной модели?]
Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как обновить драйвера на интегрированной видеокарте данной модели? Подобрать через NVidia "помошник" не выходит. Самостоятельно подобрать тоже не выйшло.

Comment: Почему вы считаете что есть более новые драйвера чем те, что у вас уже установлены?

Comment: Вообщем, скачал игру, запускаю и вижу черные меготяшие полосы по экрану. Думаю что это из-за старых драйверов

Comment: А еще из-за аппаратных проблем, проблем с ОС, с самой игрой и так далее.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Подробнее об аппаратных проблемах - это на несколько тысяч страниц. О программных проблемах - примерно столько же.

Comment: Идете сюда http://support.amd.com/ru-ru/download выбираете Notebook Graphics - Radeon HD Series - Radeon HD 7600M Series - Свою операционную систему. Качаете что предложит из последнего и пробуете установить.

Comment: Может всё-таки для дискретной, а не интегрированной видюхи? И как связаны NVidia и AMD/Intel?

Comment: Выбирал Notebook Graphics - Radeon HD Series - Radeon HD 7600M Series - Свою операционную систему на сайте support.amd.com/ru-ru/download. Скачал и начал установку, вскоре все прекрасно заработало. Спасибо, Visman

Answer (score 0):

У вас видеокарта от AMD утилита от NVIDIA не поможет. По данной [ссылке](https://drp.su/ru/devices/video/amd/amd-radeon-hd-6700m-series) можете скачать нужный вам драйвер.